# This topic is on VBscript used for reading result from a file

Tags: vbscript

I understand that the FSO does not know to read the lines from the last in a file. 
My scenario here is to validate the last but 1 line and get the result out of it.

Assume, if i need to get the result as PASS or FAIL in the last but 1 line. Since i go through from the first line, the scenario of me getting the correct result is limited because there is a probability of PASS or FAIL appearing in the file earlier.

My last 2 lines in the file is 
Failed
Done!!!!

OR

Passed
Done!!!!

to get the actual i am using a NESTED IF validation to get the result. Below is the snippet of the same.

```
 str1 = "Passed"
    str2 = "Failed"
    str3="Done!!!!"
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        str=objFile.ReadLine
        if StrComp(str, str1) = 0 Then
            str=objFile.ReadLine
        if StrComp(str,str3) = 0 Then
            result="PASS"
        End if
        elseif StrComp(str, str2) = 0 Then
            str = objFile.ReadLine
            if StrComp(str,str3) = 0 Then
                result="FAIL"
            End if
        End if
        Loop
```

This affects the performance. Is there any alternative to get this implementation in a better manner?

Comment: Why tag with `vb.net`? Looks more like VBScript.

Comment: VB6 != VB.Net != VBA. Please use only tags that are relevant to your question. Do not just add tags that sound familiar or that start with the same letters. A cat and a car are not the same thing just because they both start with the letters 'ca". Tags have specific meaning and use here. If you're not sure if a tag applies, read it's description. If you're still not sure, don't use it; someone here will add it if it's needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function which takes a file name and returns the second to last line read:

```
Function PenultimateLine(fname)
    Dim fso, ts, line1, line2

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(fname)

    Do Until ts.AtEndOfStream
        line1 = line2
        line2 = ts.ReadLine
    Loop
    ts.Close

    PenultimateLine = line1
End Function
```

You can use this function to extract the line and then test it against "PASS" or "FAIL" (which, by the way, can be done simply with `=` rather than `StrCmp`)

Answer (score 1):

```
A = Split(objfile.readall, vbcrlf)
B = A(ubound(A)-2)
```

This uses memory and is unsuitable on very large files.